# Browser relative positioning with jQuery and CutyCapt

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, positioning, css-position

I've been using CutyCapt to take screen shots of several web pages with great success.  My challenge now is to paint a few dots on those screen shots that represent where a user clicked.

CutyCapt goes through a process of resizing the web page to the scroll width before taking a screen shot.  That's extremely useful because you only get content and not much (if any) of the page's background.

My challenge is trying to map a user's mouse X coordinates to the screen shot.  Obviously users have different screen resolutions and have their browser window open to different sizes.  The image below shows 3 examples with the same logo.  Assume, for example, that the logo is 10 pixels to the left edge of the "content" area (in red).

In each of these cases, and for any resolution, I need a JavaScript routine that will calculate that the logo's X coordinate is 10.  Again, the challenge (I think) is differing resolutions.  In the center-aligned examples, the logo's position, as measured from the left edge of the browser (in black), differs with changing browser size.  The left-aligned example should be simple as the logo never moves as the screen resizes.

Can anyone think of a way to calculate the scrollable width of a page?  In other words, I'm looking for a JavaScript solution to calculate the minimum width of the browser window before a horizontal scroll bar shows up.  And I need to do this without first knowing any element IDs or class names.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total space an element needs:

```
function getWidth(x){
    var totalWidth = x.width();
    totalWidth += parseInt(x.css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt(x.css("padding-right"), 10); //Total Padding Width
    totalWidth += parseInt(x.css("margin-left"), 10) + parseInt(x.css("margin-right"), 10); //Total Margin Width
    totalWidth += parseInt(x.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt(x.css("borderRightWidth"), 10); //Total Border Width 
    return totalWidth;

 }
```

You have to add that to the position of the element:

```
$('#yourlogo').offset().left;
```

So:

```
var window-width =  $('#yourlogo').offset().left + getWidth($('#yourlogo'));
```

Hope this helps :-??

Comment: Thanks for the good start.  What I'm trying to do is calculate how far the red area is from the edge of the user's browser for any website (i.e. I don't know element ids or classes ahead of time).

In other words, I'm looking for a generic JavaScript function to figure out the width of a web page's "content" area.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I think it's pretty hard to know where the content starts , the page may be centered, but there may be a CONTACT US div to the left of the page... You could check for each element of the body the "left" atribute and see which one is the closest to the edge :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then this is what should work for you!

```
var browserWidth=$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
```

It should return the width of the persons browser window.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for how far the content area (in red above) is from the left edge of a user's browser (in black above).  Getting the client width is arbitrary - I need to measure where the horizontally scrollable content actually begins.  In other words, as you resize your browser window, eventually a horizontal scrollbar will display when you've reached the content's minimum width.  I need said width (i.e. the width of "just the content."